# kdb update multiple columns corresponding to multiple where clauses

Tags: kdb

I have a table, which is :

```
t:([]a:1 3 2 1 2 3 3 2 1;b:10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90;c:100 200 300 400 500 600 700 800 900)
```

And I want all c to be 0 where a is equal to 2, and all be to be 0 where a is equal to 1.

Currently I have these two codes:

```
t:update b:0 from t where a=1

t:update c:0 from t where a=2
```

My question is how to combine these two lines of codes into one. Because I am working on a table which is far bigger than this simple example and it will take me a lot of rows of codes to do all the updates, which is too long.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [vector conditional](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#vector-conditional) for this:

```
update b:?[a=1;0;b], c:?[a=2;0;c] from t
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help!